# How does the grouped product module display the linked position attribute?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the grouped-product module and can't seem to understand how it displays the linked attribute `position`. When adding my own linked product attribute which has data associated to the associated products I only see empty values. However, if I echo out `$linkItem->getExtensionAttributes()->getMytestattribute()` in the `fillData()` function I see the values on my screen.

`Magento\GroupedProduct\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Grouped`

I see this:

```
protected function fillData(ProductInterface $linkedProduct, ProductLinkInterface $linkItem)
{
    ....
    return [
        ....
        'position' => $linkItem->getPosition(),
        ....
    ];
}
```

And this:

```
/**
 * Fill meta columns
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function fillMeta()
{
    return [
        ....
        'position' => [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Number::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                        'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => 'position',
                        'sortOrder' => 100,
                        'visible' => false, //change to true and it shows this field with the assigned values for position
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

However, I don't see `position` inside of `\view\adminhtml\ui_component\grouped_product_listing.xml`. I want to achieve the same thing by adding a linked product attribute to a new column for the **associated products grid** and not the popup where you add more products to the grid.

What am I missing here??

**Update**:
I figured out you can add `'value' => 'My data should populate here'` to the `fillMeta` function for the new column but not sure how to pass data to that field or even if this is the correct way to pass data to this new column?

**Example**:

```
    'mytestattribute' => [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Number::NAME,
                    'formElement' => Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                    'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => 'mytestattribute',
                    'label' => __('My Test Attribute'),
                    'fit' => true,
                    'sortOrder' => 85,
                    'value' => 'My data should populate here',
                    'validation' => [
                        'validate-number' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Hi, I can't even get the echo to work on my new attribute, how did you get that far? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hate to answer my own questions but since this took a long time to debug I thought I would save others from hours of the same headaches I faced.

It appears that the `sortOrder` in the `Modifier Pool` is very important. Although I know it loads the specified files in a certain order based on the value you set I'm still not sure what file or how it was removing my data from the column based on the lower value.

Originally I had the `sortOrder` set to `72` if I remember right but after changing that value to `130` my missing column data appeared.

`\Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\di.xml`

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="package" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Package</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```